# Why not to always use size_t as our type for variables?

Tags: c

I know that `size_t` or `ssize_t` (signed) will become the type of the return value which comes from the thing we assigning to it, but my question is why not always use `size_t`? I mean, why get trouble when using `char`, `int` or etc when `size_t` can automatically know which data type we should use?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    size_t x = strlen("Hello");

    printf("String lenth of Hello is: %ld", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not always use red color when pointing things, why bother with different paints?

Comment: `size_t` is only the approprate type for values that represent the size of an object. Why would you use it for something like prices?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Haha jokes, sorry man I'm just new to this stuff

Comment: C is a high(ish) level language, providing certain abstractions and certain checks, including rudimentary type checking as well. By using proper types you declare your intention in the first place, apart from certain functional differences pointed by others, and these intentions can be verified for consistence by the compiler or other people.

Comment: "_will become the type of the return value which comes from the thing we assigning to it_" - what does this mean? where did you read that? I can't quite understand what you're trying to say, but if you're saying it's a magic or deduced type, neither is the case.

Comment: @underscore_d i.e `size_t x = return_int(5);`, `size_t` will become `int` and act like an `int`.

Comment: @MohsenFakhrizadeh Not sure where you heard that, but it's completely untrue.

Comment: `size_t` is a _type_alias_, it is not an intrinsic type.  It is _named_ to reflect its purpose, it is not a general purpose integer value and is not "magic" as you seem to think.

Comment: In this case because a `char` is always one byte, but if `x` was type `int` you should cast the result of `strlen` to `int`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I read about it [here](https://jameshfisher.com/2016/11/29/size_t_iterator/), there is an example and then __"it is the type of the return value of the sizeof operator, and of the strlen function."__

Comment: @MohsenFakhrizadeh That doesn't say the same thing as you said! Yes, both `sizeof` and `strlen` return a `size_t`. That doesn't mean `size_t` changes meaning for operators/functions that return something else!

Comment: I am not sure how that quoted statement draws you to the conclusion that `size_t` magically represents whatever type is assigned to it! C is statically typed, and `size_t` is simply an alias - look in your toolchain's stddef.h to see it or test `sizeof(size_t).

Comment: If you want variables that just accept whatever is assigned to them and adopt that type, you need Python or Javascript.  Also choose your sources carefully I would not regard one random blogger as definitive.  https://android.jlelse.eu/magic-lies-here-statically-typed-vs-dynamically-typed-languages-d151c7f95e2b

Answer (score 2):

> I know that size_t or ssize_t (signed) will become the type of the return value which comes from the thing we assigning to it

That is not true. These are specific types, and their width is fixed like that of any other type. But the width will be appropriate for your platform (it should be enough to store any address on that platform).

The closest thing to what you describe is C++'s `auto` keyword, which deduces the type it should resolve to from the thing you're initialising. But `auto` in C means something else (it's a storage specifier) and there is no equivalent mechanism for this kind of type deduction.

> I mean, why get trouble when using char, int or etc when size_t can automatically know which data type we should use?

Although this premise is flawed (as discussed above), there's still a good question here: if `size_t` is enough to store any address on our system (and `ssize_t` is large enough for any pointer difference on that system) then why risk using other types?

Simply put, we may not be storing addresses. Some numbers in our project may need to be bigger; some numbers may always be smaller and so we can save memory. It all comes down to a trade-off between resources and requirements.

If you're thinking that computer memory is usually quite plentiful nowadays, so people might as well just stick to `int` or `size_t` for all their numbers unless otherwise needed, that's kind of true in many applications, and as such people *do* tend to stick to those types without giving it much further thought. Unfortunately this habit also leads to unexpected bugs when it's not been planned out carefully enough.

Even if you were using C++'s `auto`, it is *still* debateable as to whether you should just "always use `auto`" or not. Sure, it saves you "worrying about it", until you find a bug and need to know what type something actually is. Personally I prefer to be explicit in my code, to *tell* my computer what I want it to do, but that seems to be a swiftly passing fad.

Comment: Hey, Thanks! So you mean that `size_t` is **always** bigger enough to store any value and because of that it wastes memory?

Comment: @MohsenFakhrizadeh Not any value, any address (i.e. pointer, array index, object size, etc). Not every value is (or relates to) an address.

Comment: Otherwise basically yeah.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Is `size_t` really spec'd to be able to store "any address"? I thought it is in theory possible to have different widths of address space and max object size, and that was why `uintptr_t` was a separate thing. I'd think `size_t` was all about _sizes_, not addresses.

Comment: Choosing smaller data types is seldom about saving memory (except perhaps in the case of large arrays).  That is not a primary reason you might do that, and if you are doing that it is often a premature optimisation.

Comment: @underscore_d True, that breaks down on systems with segmented addressing. It's really about object sizes. For most platforms, though, the result is the same and I simplified ;)

Comment: @Clifford I was thinking precisely of large arrays. The only other reason I can think of is direct packing/unpacking of data to/from an external source (e.g. over a network). Theoretically sticking to word sizes helps your performance but I think that ship sailed many moons ago.

Comment: Sure, but the OP has gone away with the impression that `size_t` somehow "_wastes space_".  I think you have to be very careful with this one - seems to draw some odd conclusions from good information.  Apart form that the answer seems to be confusing `size_t` with `ptrdiff_t` / `intptr_t` / `uintptr_t` as suggested by @underscore_d

Comment: @Clifford Well, it _does_ "waste space" (okay, modulo padding & alignment here and there); the only question is how much you (as the programmer at the time) care.

Comment: It occupies more space that a smaller type - that is not the same as wasting it.  On the discussion of pointers, I appreciate that the requirements of `size_t` are defined in those terms, but that hardly reflects with _purpose_.  I think it is confusing to put it in those terms, and goodness knows he's confuse already.

Comment: For automatic variables when you have plenty of stack space, there is little to be gained by 'saving space'.

Comment: @WeatherVane I concur. Though that doesn't mean that none is saved ;)

Comment: @Clifford You're free to write your own answer; the key point of mine is that (a) `size_t` does not deduce, and (b) even if it did, that's not a golden bullet for good code. The rest is just waffle :P It's not supposed to be a comprehensive discussion on the ins and outs of data types and memory management.

Comment: To be honest I was struggling to understand the question until you interpreted it.  It is such an astonishingly left-field interpretation of the semantics.  It was not really a criticism of the answer, rather a caution that the OP seems to wilfully misunderstand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ssize_t` as a "universal signed integer" type of variable.  `ssize_t` is a POSIX type, and it's not universal.

[And per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):

> The type `ssize_t` shall be capable of storing values at least in the range `[-1, {SSIZE_MAX}]`.

So `ssize_t` is not guaranteed to represent a range of negative numbers, unlike `long` or `int32_t`.